# Update my trigger for multiple row insert, update and delete?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger, sql-query-store

I am creating a new trigger for whatever action performed on master table, I need to update my local table using trigger for Insert,Update and Delete. But now I am facing issue during multiple row insert or update.

I had created trigger but it's not working properly for multiple row insertion and update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_pspartmas] ON [dbo].[ps_partmas]
AFTER INSERT
    ,UPDATE
    ,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmp_id VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @sl_type VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @sl_code VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @sl_desc VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @region_code VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @tranYN VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @IT_NO VARCHAR(50)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------Fetching recored from inserted
-- SELECT @cmp_id=cmp_id,@sl_type=cl_supp_code,@sl_code=part_code,@sl_desc=part_nm,@region_code=region_code,@tranYN=Stop_Order,@it_NO=IT_no
-- FROM inserted
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------if recored were deletd
SELECT @cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(cmp_id))
    ,@sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(part_code))
    ,@sl_desc = rtrim(ltrim(part_nm)) --,@tranYN=rtrim(ltrim(Stop_Order))
FROM deleted

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM view_sl_code1
        WHERE cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(@cmp_id))
            AND sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_code))
            AND sl_type = @sl_type
        )
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        DELETE
        FROM view_sl_code1
        WHERE cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(@cmp_id))
            AND sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_code))
            AND sl_type = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_type))
    END
END

SELECT @cmp_id = cmp_id
    ,@sl_type = cl_supp_code
    ,@sl_code = part_code
    ,@sl_desc = part_nm
    ,@region_code = region_code
    ,@tranYN = Stop_Order
    ,@it_NO = IT_no
FROM inserted

--@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM view_sl_code1
        WHERE cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(@cmp_id))
            AND sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_code))
            AND sl_type = @sl_type
        )
BEGIN
    UPDATE view_sl_code1
    SET sl_desc = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_desc))
        ,tranYN = rtrim(ltrim(@tranYN))
        ,actions = 'partmas_up'
        ,date_update = GETDATE()
    WHERE cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(@cmp_id))
        AND sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_code))
END

------------------------------------------------------------------------------inserting new recored
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM view_sl_code1
        WHERE cmp_id = rtrim(ltrim(@cmp_id))
            AND sl_code = rtrim(ltrim(@sl_code))
            AND sl_type = @sl_type
        )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO view_sl_code1 (
        cmp_id
        ,sl_type
        ,sl_code
        ,sl_desc
        ,region_code
        ,tranYN
        ,IT_NO
        ,actions
        ,date_update
        )
    SELECT rtrim(ltrim(cmp_id))
        ,rtrim(ltrim(cl_supp_code)) AS sl_type
        ,rtrim(ltrim(part_code)) AS sl_code
        ,rtrim(ltrim(part_nm)) AS sl_desc
        ,rtrim(ltrim(region_code))
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Stop_Order = 'Y'
                THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END AS tranYN
        ,IT_NO
        ,'partmas_in'
        ,getdate()
    FROM dbo.ps_partmas
    WHERE cmp_id = @cmp_id
        AND part_code = @sl_code
        AND cl_supp_code = @sl_type
END
--end
PRINT 'Trigger is activated'
END
```

I need to capture all the inserted and updated values in my local table.

Could you please suggest?

Comment: It would be much easier to assist if you could simplify your problem. [mcve]

Comment: why is multi row insertion a problem? Treating data as a bach instead of induvidual rows is almost always a better approach. Also: The code you posted suggests that you know how to access the `inserted` table but you never do anything with it. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Triggers should *never* be written this way. Dont consider this as not working for multiple rows, think of it as not working as triggers *must* not fail for multi row updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply join to the inserted and deleted tables.

Here is an example. I have removed all the ltrim/rtrim for readability, add it back if you need it.

```
delete view_sl_code1
from view_sl_code1
join deleted 
    on deleted.cmp_id=view_sl_code1.cmp_id
    and deleted.sl_code=view_sl_code1.sl_code
    and deleted.sl_desc=view_sl_code1.sl_desc

update view_sl_code1
    SET sl_desc = inserted.sl_desc
    ,tranYN = inserted.tranYN
    ,actions = 'partmas_up'
    ,date_update = GETDATE()
from view_sl_code1
join inserted 
    on inserted.cmp_id = view_sl_code1.cmp_id
    AND inserted.sl_code = view_sl_code1.sl_code

insert view_sl_code1 (
        cmp_id
        ,sl_type
        ,sl_code
        ,sl_desc
        ,region_code
        ,tranYN
        ,IT_NO
        ,actions
        ,date_update
        )
select cmp_id,
    cl_supp_code AS sl_type
    ,part_code AS sl_code
    ,part_nm AS sl_desc
    ,region_code
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Stop_Order = 'Y'
            THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
        END AS tranYN
    ,IT_NO
    ,'partmas_in'
    ,getdate()
FROM dbo.ps_partmas
join inserted 
    on inserted.cmp_id = ps_partmas.cmp_id
    AND inserted.part_code = ps_partmas.sl_code
    AND inserted.cl_supp_code = ps_partmas.sl_type
where not exists(
    SELECT *
    FROM view_sl_code1
    join inserted
        on inserted.cmp_id = view_sl_code1.cmp_id
        AND inserted.sl_code = view_sl_code1.sl_code
        AND inserted.sl_type = view_sl_code1.sl_type        
)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom....if condition required or not in your case as i mentioned in my trigger?

Comment: You cant use an if because it tests on a single row. You need to do it in where clauses, such as the `where not exists` I used. You dont need it in the update because it wont update if the row doesnt exist.

Comment: Hi Tom ,
Hope you are good!!

trigger is not working for bulk insertion or multiple row insertion.
could you please suggest ?

Comment: Not unless you provide an error message. I don't have your database so it could be a simple typo or syntax error.

Comment: It's not getting error but rows are greater than one then only one row is inserted in Audit Table.

Comment: I cant speak to the logic of your inserts, I just updated your original insert/update statements so they would work with the whole set. What I would do is dump the whole contents of Deleted and Inserted into a temporary table, then do some debugging from there. I suspect the joins your insert query are doing between ps_partmas and inserted is wrong, or possibly the exists check. Without having the tables its hard to know.